# Check for network connection in Observable before performing API calls

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I am trying to use the following function to check for network connection

```
 private boolean isThereInternetConnection() {
        boolean isConnected;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isConnected = (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());

        return isConnected;
    }
```

Then call it before I do API calls like:

```
public Observable<UserEntity> userEntity(int page) {                                        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<UserEntity>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super UserEntity> subscriber) {
                if (isThereInternetConnection()) {
                  // I want to return:
                return mUserApi.UserEntity(items,page);
                // in:
                  subscriber.onNext()
                } // otherwise return no internet connection message
            }
        });
```

Mind that `mUserApi.UserEntity(items,page);`is a call to interface returns observable object like:

```
@GET("/user")
    Observable <UserEntity> UserEntity(@Query("user_ids") String user_id, @Query("page") int  page);
```

Comment: for more details, did you add the permission "network state" in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

There is your rest call:

```
@GET("/user")
Observable <UserEntity> UserEntity(@Query("user_ids") String user_id, @Query("page") int  page);
```

In your class where you initialize the restAdapter, implement the UserEntity:

```
public Observable<UserEntity> getUserEntity(String userId, int page){
    return myRestAdapterInterface.UserEntity(userId, page);
}
```

Make your observable which will emit the data:

```
public Observable<UserEntity> userEntity(String userId, int page) {
    return getUserEntity(userId, page).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
//you can map, filter or do anything here   
}
```

Then subscribe for the data:

```
userEntity("id",5).subscribe(new Observer<UserEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            //doSomething if u want
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            //handle error
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<UserEntity> userEntity) {
            //do something with the data
        }
    });
```

And for the connection checking, create your own client for retrofit:

```
public class ConnectivityAwareUrlClient implements Client {

private Context context;
private Client wrappedClient;

public ConnectivityAwareUrlClient(Context context, Client client) {
    this.context = context;
    this.wrappedClient = client;

}

@Override
public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
    if (!ConnectivityUtil.isConnected(context)) {
        throw RetrofitError.unexpectedError("No internet", new NoConnectivityException("No Internet"));
    } else {
        Response response = wrappedClient.execute(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

}

And when configurating the RestAdapter use it:

```
RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(serverHost)
                 .setClient(new ConnectivityAwareUrlClient(new OkHttpClient(), ...))
```

Comment: I have tried the same but I got an error message saying: error: incompatible types: Observable<UserEntity> cannot be converted to CAP#1
                    subscriber.onNext(mUserApi.userEntiry(items,page));
                                                              ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:

Comment: thanks for your help. but i still don't understand on where should i do the internet checks before i make call to api. if do that on the subscriber on error method, this will mean that the checks will be done incase of error not before api call

Comment: Oh.. okay, i thought you don't know how to implement the Observable. Edited the answer, added the internet checking.